# How to use translation in a directive field?

Tags: angular, translation, ngx-translate

I building an Angular app and I want to add the translation in my whole application. For that, I'm using the [ngx-translation method](https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-angular7-app-with-ngx-translate). I have got an issue when I build translation with parameters: my app displays [Object object].
I used a directive which is using [message] field, and this value needs to be translated, but I do not know how to add the translation in my message value.

My component is the following:

```
<app-confirmation-dialog  
[translate]="'demo.greeting'" 
[translateParams]="{name: 'Andreas'}"
[message]="?????????"
[confirmationLabel]="'quit anyway'"
(onConfirmation)="onCancel()"></app-confirmation-dialog>
```

I added the same key in my translation file:

```
{
  ....
  "demo": {
    "greeting": "Hello {{name}}!"
  }
  ....
}
```

Do you have any idea to add the translation in my message value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to easily use the directive form of translation in this case because you are passing `message` as an attribute of an element (in this case, an input of a directive). If you keep using the directive form `[translate]` then it's going to mess with your own directive in a way you don't want.

Instead, use the pipe form, passing the parameters object as an argument:

```
<app-confirmation-dialog
  [message]="'demo.greeting' | translate: {name: 'Andreas'}"
  [confirmationLabel]="'quit anyway'"
  (onConfirmation)="onCancel()">
</app-confirmation-dialog>
```

Comment: Very helpful Thank you

Comment: and what happen when we have a function in the message field please ?  ` `[confirmationLabel]="getConfirmationLabelOfPromptDialog()" `  and in the component.ts file you have this : `getConfirmationLabelOfPromptDialog(): string {
    return "I'm done";
  }`

Comment: sorry I forgot to identify you in my last question @zicon

Comment: @shtb2708 I've never done it before, but as far as I know it should be as simple as `[confirmationLabel]="getConfirmationLabelOfPromptDialog() | translate"`

Comment: I tried this way and it just display the `getConfirmationLabelOfPromptDialog()` function on the screen  @zircon, you might have known the way to code, thank you for your help and if you find the solution I will be happy to know it

Comment: Make sure you included the parentheses and that the function name is not in single quotes. Worst case scenario, you can subscribe to `translate.get('I\'m done')` in your component code and set it to a variable member to pass to the directive.